# Detect when new file is added to a directory

Tags: file, directory, erlang, gen-server

How can I detect a new file being added to a specific directory?

What I am looking for is something like an event_listener for when a new file is created. I am not interested in using a loop that keeps searching the directory for new files because I need the name of the file when it is added to the directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you are working on Unix like OS you should consider using inotifywait tool.
I just found nice Erlang wrapper around useful system tools: https://github.com/sdanzan/erlang-systools

Comment: this seems to be using a loop too and i am looking for something like a trigger

Comment: It's efficient triggered based loop. By using this tool you are subscribing to a file system for specific changes and get notified. It's fine. Read about that: [link1](http://www.infoq.com/articles/inotify-linux-file-system-event-monitoring)  [link2](http://blog.lagentz.com/general/automate-your-shell-scripts-using-inotify-and-inotifywait/)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, **there is no native Erlang API** to perform what you are looking for.

Any non-polling solution has to rely on specific APIs from the operating system. On MacOS X and FreeBSD, you could use [kqueue(2)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=kqueue) API. On Linux, you could use [inotify(7)](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify) API. Both APIs work with [select(2)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=select) and you can use Erlang's [driver_select](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_driver.html#driver_select) function to select on the file descriptors provided by these APIs. Writing such a driver is not extremely difficult.

You can find on Github [several drivers for inotify](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=erlang+inotify) and [one driver for kqueue](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=erlang+kqueue&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults).

Answer (score 0):

[inoteefy](https://github.com/massemanet/inotify) gives you a nice listener based api on top of the Linux `inotify` api. Example for listening to updates to `/tmp/`:

```
1> inoteefy:watch("/tmp/", fun(X) -> io:format("File event: ~p~n", [X]) end).       
ok
File event: {"/tmp/",[create],0,"foo.txt"}
File event: {"/tmp/",[open],0,"foo.txt"}
File event: {"/tmp/",[attrib],0,"foo.txt"}
File event: {"/tmp/",[close_write],0,"foo.txt"}
```

here I'm doing `touch /tmp/foo.txt` after starting the watch